# Creating individual variables automatically from a looped list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to get every number in a list multiplied by a float number, I googled about unpacking a list into individual variables but I couldn't get it working since my list lenght is dependant on how much numbers the user wants.

```
multip = False
randomnumber = 518.37 #random float number to get multiplied
    wannamult = input("ENABLE MULTIPLICATION? Y/N  ").lower()

    if wannamult == "y":
        multip = True
        multlist = []
        multinput = input("ENTER NUMBERS: (.) to end  ")
        while multinput != ".":
            multlist.append(multinput)
            multinput = input("ENTER NUMBERS: (.) to end  ")
    else:
        pass
```

Then, if `multip` is True, I want to create a variable that retains the value of the multiplication between `randomnumber` and every number the user has added to the list:

```
        if multip == True:
            calc = multlist * randomnumber 
"""How can I make it create individual variables automatically with its respective value from the list?"""
            calc = str(calc) #conversion for print 
            print ("The result of " + randomnumber + " multiplied by " + (every number in the list displayed individually) + " is " + calc)
```

This is what I got so far, obviously I can't fix it without your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should take a look at [`for` loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# get numbers from user, each separated by space, put into a list
nums = [int(e) for e in input("Enter numbers: ").split()]

# multiply each number with 2.5, print on screen
print([e*2.5 for e in nums])
```

Comment: I tried it out and seems to work, but it only gets one number so I added a loop and it's actually never ending now. May you take a look at it? https://pastebin.com/8SQpXgwQ

Comment: type numbers on one line separated by spaces and press ENTER at the end. That is how input() works. You don't need a while loop. All the numbers will be assigned as elements of a list named nums.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` to apply a function to each item of a list :

```
>>> L = [1, 3, 6, 8, 4]
>>> list(map(lambda x: x*1.5, L))
[1.5, 4.5, 9.0, 12.0, 6.0]
```

`lambda` is just a way to create anonymous function. You can use a function defined elsewhere in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard list comprehension:

```
multiplier = 10
items = [1,2,3,4]
result = [item * multiplier for item in items]
print(result)
```